# NextAuth SignIn Action, giving error Window is not defined

Tags: next-auth

My goal is just to create a easy signIn page with NextAuth, I wanted to use the new form action altough I get back the error:

ReferenceError: window is not defined
(webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/next-auth/react/index.js:259:172)

Here is my code:

SignIn Page

```
'use client';

import { signInAction } from "@/app/actions/signIn";
import { useFormState } from "react-dom";


export default function Page() {
    const [state, formAction] = useFormState(signInAction, null);

    return (
        <form action={formAction} method="POST">
            <label htmlFor="email">
                Email
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="Email..."
                    required
                />
            </label>
                <label htmlFor="password">
                Password
                <input
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    placeholder="Password..."
                    required
                />
            </label>
            
            <button type="submit">SignIn</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

SignInAction Page

```
'use server'

import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";

export type SignInActionResult = {
    status: "error";
    errorMessage: string;
} | undefined;

export async function signInAction(
    previousState: SignInActionResult | null,
    formData: FormData,
): Promise<SignInActionResult> {
    console.log(formData)

    try {
        const email = formData.get("email");
        const password = formData.get("password");

        const result = await signIn('credentials', {
            redirect: true, 
            email,
            password,
            callbackUrl: '/protected'
        });

        return {
            status: "error",
            errorMessage: "Failed to signIn, invalid email or password.",
        } as const;

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)

        return {
            status: "error",
            errorMessage: "Failed to signIn, invalid email or password.",
        } as const;
    }
}
```

Thank you